# Laravel Extend BaseController and Vendor controller

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, laravel, multiple-inheritance

I'm using [Jacopo Authentication package](https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl) in one of my sites, I'm extending it to add some methods and do stuff after I call its methods, I'm extending it like this:

```
<?php
use Jacopo\Authentication\Controllers\UserController as JacopoUserController;
class UserController extends JacopoUserController{
...
}
```

Now, the problem is that I need to use some methods from my BaseController, whats the best way to be able to use BaseController here? Should I just instantiate it? Maybe move as much logic as I can to a Model or Helper and duplicate a little code? Is there anything like this?

```
class UserController extends JacopoUserController extends BaseController{
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend only one class in PHP. However you could create [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and put there functionality from `Basecontroller` and to use this functionality simple add `use Traitname;` to class that needs that functionality